# Add control/event dynamically doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

Any help would be appreciated --

here is my aspx code -

```
<div id="div_Detail" class="div_det" runat="server" />
```

and in my code behind -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  LoadDetail();
}

private void LoadDetail() {
    HtmlTable tbl = new HtmlTable();
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();

    Button bUpdate = new Button();
    bUpdate.Text = "Update";
    bUpdate.Click += this.Update_Click;

    cell.Controls.Add(bUpdate);
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
    tbl.Rows.Add(row);
    div_Detail.Controls.Add(tbl);
}

private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Do something
}
```

I see the button on the page with the correct text. But on clicking that button, Update_Click never gets called.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the button an id.  The .NET engine needs IDs on controls during postback to associate the control with a given event delegate.

Edit:

This code works fine:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        LoadDetail();
    }

    private void LoadDetail() {
        HtmlTable tbl = new HtmlTable();
        HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();

        Button bUpdate = new Button();
        bUpdate.Text = "Update";
        bUpdate.Click += this.Update_Click;
        bUpdate.ID = "btnID";

        cell.Controls.Add(bUpdate);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
        div_Detail.Controls.Add(tbl);
    }

    private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Do something 
    }
```

Comment: I added the ID, but it still just comes back into Page_Load with IsPostback = true. It doesn't get to the event.

Comment: That code by itself works, but not within my application. I tried to simplify it for posting purposes, but essentially I have a div that holds a tab container with 2 tabs. Those tabs have divs that hold tables where this button does. There is about 3000 lines of code within the entire page.  Would there be another reason why this only comes back into Page_Load()?

Comment: If you have multple controls with the same IDs, or AJAX controls doing something else, yes, that could get in the way.

Comment: There is definitely only one control with that ID. And I have several AJAX callbacks on other controls, but nothing that affects controls within that div.

Comment: The only way this code will not work is if the control creation doesn't happen on every round trip (postback).  Check to make sure this method gets called on every trip and that it is at the top of the list of things to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Give the button an Id and everything will work fine.

`bUpdate.Id = "btnUpdate";`

Answer (score 1):

Try This one may help u

```
    bUpdate.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bUpdate_OnClick);

protected void bUpdate_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {


}
```